# I want affected rows data and column which has affected by update query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Is there a way to obtain only the affected columns after an update query?
After an update query, that involves 10 columns, I know that only 2 columns are
really updated (because the values of the other cols don't change).
I need to know the names of the changed cols, for logging purpose.

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET name = $name,......................,column10=10 WHERE id=$id")->result();
$this->db->affected_rows();
```

This code gives number of affected rows but i want the data and updated 
 column information.

Comment: Could you post also the code you use for the query. That would help others.

Comment: now i am only using   $this->db->afffected_rows();   For get number of affected rows. i don't have any idea how can i get affected columns.

Comment: I meant the actual update query. Posting the whole code section would help knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: that is the query i am using.

Comment: @Vikas that query is no way updating 10 columns, it only updates `name` column

Comment: @HastaDhana Bro i know about it. its just an example for update query which have i used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no built-in CodeIgniter functionality for that. You could compare old value with new value though :

```
$last_record = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
$this->db->query("UPDATE `table1` SET name = $name,......................,column10=10 WHERE id=$id")->result();
// $this->db->affected_rows();
$new_record = $this->db->get_where('table1', array('id' => $id))->row_array();
$affected_columns = array_diff($new_record, $last_record);
foreach ($affected_columns as $field => $value) {
    echo "[field] : $field\r\n";
    echo "[old_value] : $last_record[$field]\r\n";
    echo "[new_value] : $value\r\n";
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

This will print each of the of the updated column with it's old-new value respectively.

Comment: Thanks!!  That is also a good idea.but if we get for sql queries its easy for me but no problem its also work like that.